# Xamarin.forms: Make Bindeable itemsource not start at 0 (without cutting the first objects)

Tags: xamarin.forms, itemsource

I am giving a list with objects to my swipeview:

```
swipeview_swipeview.ItemsSource = data;
```

However, the itemview always then starts at object 0. (At the beginning).

But maybe I just want to feed it my whole data set, but make it start at object 3.

I tried

```
swipeview_swipeview.ItemsSource = data[3].
```

But that doesnt work.

I can ofcours just cut the objects from the list and then give it to the itemsource of the swipeview but I do NOT want to alter or copy the list. I just want it to NOT start at object zero but at object X.

Is there anyway of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

use LINQ

```
using System.Linq;

swipeview_swipeview.ItemsSource = data.Skip(1);
```

Comment: Hello, does this skip the first object, or does this skip one object beginning at the first?

Comment: "Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns the remaining elements."